# spark-cassandra connection failed over TLS in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, tls1.2, spark-cassandra-connector

I am getting 'no cipher suits in common' exception when trying to connect spark with cassandra.

Java version : openjdk 8 (build version > 161; unlimited jce)

TLS : 1.2

Cipher Suits: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

```
4.1.42.Final.jar:4.1.42.Final] 
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:444) ~[netty-all-4.1.42.Final.jar:4.1.42.Final]
        ... 15 common frames omitted

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:198) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1667) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:333) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:321) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
```

Answer (score 1):

You've posted very limited information so it's difficult to diagnose the problem. The exception indicates that there is no common cipher suites between the Cassandra cluster and the connector.

Check the cipher suites configured on the Cassandra nodes and compare them to the algorithms you've configured on the spark-cassandra-connector. They need to have at least one cipher in common.

You need to make sure that you've configured the connector with the right settings, particularly:

```
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.protocol
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.enabledAlgorithms
```

See the [spark-cassandra-connector SSL Options](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#cassandra-ssl-connection-options) for details. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Erick. Forgot to mention ssl algorithm used at spark end.

I got above exception when I used '  - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256' cipher in Spark, but it was solved when I change it to 'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256'. Now I am getting 'Fatal Error: Starting SSL failed: certificate unknown' error.

Here is my client encryption in cassandra.yml
`
client_encryption_options: 
  cipher_suites:
  - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
  - TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
  enabled: true
  keystore: /etc/cassandra/conf/encryption/cql/keystore.jks
`

Comment: _'certificate_unknown'_ error is solved now as I forgot to add common CA in my custom _truststore_ inside Spark container.